# The Lyapunov inequality for a given matrix $P$

Tags: matrices, inequality, linear-control, lyapunov-functions, linear-matrix-inequality

The famous Lyapunov theory says if a system matrix $A$ is stable, then the Lyapunov inequality $$A^TP+PA<0, \qquad P>0$$ is unique which depends on the negative definite matrix $-Q$, which I didn’t write in the inequality above. Given a stable matrix $A$, is it true that $A^TP+PA<0$ for all matrices $P>0$?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. My best guess is that you're asking one of the following questions. 1: "given a matrix $P > 0$, does there exist a stable matrix $A$ such that $A^T P + PA < 0$?" 2: "given a stable matrix $A$, is it true that $A^TP + PA < 0$ for all matrices $P>0$?". Please [edit] your post to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you! The first question I think the answer is yes.The second one is exactly what I was asking! This is the first time I use this platform, sorry for my unclear expressions.

Comment: The answer is “no” even if $A$ is negative definite. See my recent [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/10052085).

Comment: Thank you！Got it！